# Unable to start iTunes due to incorrect version of Quicktime

Tags: itunes, updates, quicktime

I am getting the following error when I try to run iTunes.

```
---------------------------
Newer Version of QuickTime Required
---------------------------
QuickTime version 7.6.2 is installed, iTunes requires QuickTime version 7.6.4 or later.

Please uninstall iTunes, then install iTunes again.
---------------------------
OK   
---------------------------
```

I have uninstalled iTunes and reinstalled from latest version from the apple website, I have tried apple update and installed all that.

Any ideas?

Update: Thanks for all the suggestions, I guess I was just annoyed because the error message is so rubbish.  When I get a chance I'll reinstall them all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try uninstalling QuickTime, then re-downloading the latest version of QuickTime 7 from [apple.com](http://www.apple.com/quicktime/download/). You may need to re-install iTunes after installing the new version of QuickTime.

Answer (score 1):

Open QuickTime and check your version. If it is out of date, update it and try again.

Answer (score 0):

This is so stupid.

Despite iTunes being a single download, in order to uninstall it you need to uninstall iTunes and Quicktime, then reinstall itunes.  Finally it is working.

Thanks for help.